# Is there any live classes for learning about Mars and Universe by professionals?

Tags: spacex, mars, nasa, isro, mars-orbiter-mission

I have 10 year old son and he is crazy about Mars, Space, Blackholes, Universe , Rockets, and Satellites. Right now he goes to youtube and tries to learn. But we don't know which video is good and does it have real information and can my son understand it properly.

I am looking for a structured course on Space tech as he is crazy about it. Preferably live Space Science classes so he can ask tons of doubts and I can also talk to teacher. Please help !

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is on topic on this site - When I was that age I was very curious about space too - 8 years later I still am ^^ I didn't go to many classes about space-related topics as I found none for my age... You should definitely get your son the books written by stephen and lucy hawking. They cover lots of space-related topics while providing a narrative that makes it even more exciting. I loved those books! Books are the best resource for curious kids!

Comment: Maybe you should also check if you have any universities nearby that have courses for children... I sometimes went to those too, often they are about more general fields of science though. You should get your son excited about those too, as without chemistry, physics etc, space-exploration isn't possible. Being curious about what's out there is a great entry point to the world of science ^^

Comment: Not classes, but Emily Lakadawalla of the Planetary Science has a list of the  [best space books for kids](https://www.planetary.org/articles/space-books-kids)

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Why have you added tags that do not seem related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any structured courses for a 10 year old, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

In the meantime I would recommend your son watch good quality documentaries, such as those produced by:

- The [BBC](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=bbc%20space%20documentaries&ia=web)
- [Nova](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=nova%20space%20documentary&ia=web)
- [National Geographic](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=national%20geographic%20space%20documentaries&ia=web&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D6NWLZJj-s_U&pn=1)
- Anything presented by [Neil deGrasse Tyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_deGrasse_Tyson), such as the 2014
  continuation of [Cosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos%3A_A_Spacetime_Odyssey)
- Anything presented by [Brian Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Cox_%28physicist%29)
- Anything presented by [Carl Sagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan), he died in 1996, so somethings
  he presented may be dated, but still worth watching - he was an excellent educator.
- Anything presented by [Michio Kaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michio_Kaku)
- Anything presented by [Jim Al-Khalili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Al-Khalili)
- Anything space related by [Stephen Hawking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking)
- Documentaries about the Apollo moon missions, such as [Last Man on
  the Moon](https://thelastmanonthemoon.com/)
- Anything from this [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=space%20documentaries&ia=web)